# Is it useless to use the `register` keyword with modern compilers, when optimizing?

Tags: c, gcc, visual-c++, clang

The C `register` keyword gives the compiler a hint to prefer storing a variable in a register rather than, say, on the stack. A compiler may ignore it if it likes. I understand that it's mostly-useless these days when you compile with optimization turned on, but is it *entirely* useless?

More specifically: For any combination of { gcc, clang, msvc } x { -Og, -O, -O2, -O3 }: Is `register` ignored when deciding whether to actually assign a register? And if not, are there cases in which it's useful enough to bother using it?

**Notes:**

- I am *not* asking whether it the keyword any *effect*; of course it does - it prevents you from using the address of that variable; and if you don't optimize at all, it will make the difference between register assignment or memory assignment for your variable.
- Answers for just one compiler / some of the above combinations are very welcome.

Comment: These days it is, as you say, usually just a hint to the compiler. And has always been considered such on register-starved CPU architectures like the x86 or the early 8-bit home-computer CPU's.

Comment: For GCC, `register` has had no effect _at all_ - not even a hint - at _all_ optimization levels, for more than a decade. (Older versions did treat it as a hint, but only at `-O0`; this stopped happening when the "simple register allocator" was removed, but I don't remember which version that was.)  However, it's still required for the [explicit register variable extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Register-Variables.html#Explicit-Register-Variables).

Comment: @zwol: And for all architectures? Good to know (not that I ever recommended using `register` for that).

Comment: @Olaf Yes, for all architectures. The state of play in GCC 2.7, which is as far back as I know, was that the "local", "global", and "reload" register allocation passes, used when optimizing, completely ignored `register`, whereas the "simple" register allocator, used when not optimizing, treated it as a hint. At some point, I *think* after 2.95 but before 2005, "simple" was scrapped in favor of teaching local+global+reload how to not optimize very much, primarily for ease of maintenance (the register allocator is really complicated, you only want to have one of 'em).

Answer (score 7):

For GCC, `register` has had no effect on code generation *at all*, not even a hint, at *all* optimization levels, for all supported CPU architectures, for over a decade.

The reasons for this are largely historical.  GCC 2.95 and older had two register allocators, one ("stupid") used when not optimizing, and one ("local, global, reload") used when optimizing.  The "stupid" allocator did try to honor `register`, but the "local, global, reload" allocator completely ignored it.  (I don't know what the original rationale for that design decision was; you'd have to ask Richard Kenner.)  In version 3.0, the "stupid" allocator was scrapped in favor of adding a fast-and-sloppy mode to "local, global, reload".  Nobody bothered to write the code to make that mode pay attention to `register`, so it doesn't.

As of this writing, the GCC devs are in the process of replacing "local, global, reload" with a new allocator called "IRA and LRA", but it, too, completely ignores `register`.

However, the (C-only) rule that you cannot take the address of a `register` variable is still enforced, and the keyword is used by the [explicit register variable extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Explicit-Register-Variables.html#Explicit-Register-Variables), which allows you to dedicate a *specific* register to a variable; this can be useful in programs that use a lot of inline assembly.

Comment: Any `gcc` documentation / source that confirms that?

Comment: @ouah Not off the top of my head, and don't have time today to dig through the manual and the mailing lists for it.

Comment: Maybe this response was true at some point, but it's demonstrably not true today (gcc-11.2) https://godbolt.org/z/acEWzoxT1.

Comment: @Luke Your test is not testing what you think it is testing.

Comment: @zwol I'm willing to believe you but that's not really a useful comment. I used the keyword "register", I got different code.

Answer (score 2):

C Standard says:

> (c11, 6.7.1p6) "A declaration of an identifier for an object with storage-class specifier register suggests that access to the object be as fast as possible. The extent to which such suggestions are effective is implementation-defined."

These suggestions being implementation-defined means the implementation must define the choices being made ((c11, J.3.8 Hints) "The extent to which suggestions made by using the register storage-class specifier are effective (6.7.1)").

Here is what the documentation of some popular C compilers says.

For `gcc` ([source](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Hints-implementation.html)):

> The register specifier affects code generation only in these ways:
>
> - When used as part of the register variable extension, see Explicit Register Variables.
> - When -O0 is in use, the compiler allocates distinct stack memory for    all variables that do not have the register storage-class
>     specifier;    if register is specified, the variable may have a
>     shorter lifespan    than the code would indicate and may never be
>     placed in memory.
> - On    some rare x86 targets, setjmp doesn’t save the registers in all    circumstances. In those cases, GCC doesn’t allocate any
>     variables in    registers unless they are marked register.

For `IAR` compiler for ARM ([source](http://ftp.iar.se/WWWfiles/arm/webic/doc/EWARM_DevelopmentGuide.ENU.pdf)):

> *Honoring the register keyword (6.7.1)*
>
> User requests for register variables are not honored

Answer (score 1):

If an object of automatic storage duration never has its address taken, a compiler may safely assume that its value can only be observed or modified by code which uses it directly.  In the absence of the `register` keyword, a compiler which generates code in single-pass fashion would have no way of knowing, given...

```
void test(int *somePointer)
{
  int i;
  for (int i=0; i<10; i+=2)
  {
    somePointer[i] = -1;
    somePointer[i+1] = 2;
```

whether the write to `somePointer[i]` might possibly write `i`.  If it could, then the compiler would be required to reload `i` when evaluating `somePointer[i+1]`.  Applying the `register` keyword to `i` would allow even a single-pass compiler to avoid the reload because it would be entitled to assume that no valid pointer could hold a value derived from the address of `i`, and consequently there was no way that writing `somePointer[i]` could affect `i`.

The `register` keyword could be useful, even today, if it were not interpreted as imposing a constraint that the address of an object cannot be exposed to anything, but rather as inviting compilers to assume that no pointer derived from an object's address will be used outside the immediate context where the address was taken, and within contexts where the address is taken the object will be accessed *only* using pointers derived from address.  Unfortunately, the only situations the Standard permits `register` qualifiers are those where an object's address is never neither used nor exported to outside code in *any* fashion--i.e. cases which a multi-pass compiler could identify *by itself* without need for the qualifier.

The `register` keyword could be useful, even with modern compilers, if it invited compilers to--at their leisure--treat any context where a `register`-qualified object's address is taken (e.g. `get_integer(&i);`) using the pattern:

```
{
  int temp = i;
  get_integer(&temp);
  i = temp;
}
```

and to assume that a register-qualified object of external scope will only be accessed in contexts which either explicitly access the object or take its address.  At present, compilers have very limited ability to cache global variables in registers across pointer accesses involving the same types; the `register` keyword could help with that except that compilers are required to treat as constraint violations all the situations where it could be useful.

Comment: What do you mean by "write `i`"? Did you mean "overwrite `i`?" But then - I disagree. The compiler is not required to keep i anywhere specific, so it can just decide `i` doesn't get accessed by that loop, and put it in a register. Doesn't seem like that breaks the standard in any way (but correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: @einpoklum: The compiler, having seen only the above code, would have no way of knowing whether code later on in the loop might check if `i` is equal to zero, and if so subtract 2 and and set `somePointer` to `&i`.  The next time through the loop, `i` would hold 0 and `somePointer` would hold its address, so `somePointer[0]=-1;` would *legitimately* set `i` to -1 (no Undefined Behavior).  Then `somePointer[i+1]=2;` would set `i` to 2, again legitimately.  If a compiler saw the whole loop before generating any code, it could tell that doesn't happen, but single-pass compilers can't do that.

Comment: s/The compiler/The mythical compiler which finalizes its decisions and generates code in a single pass/ ?

Comment: @einpoklum: Single-pass compilers aren't used much today, but the `register` keyword was added to the language at a time when the speed advantages of single-pass compilation were very important.

Comment: Fair enough, but this is a question about modern compilers. Also, I'm kind of skeptical the benefit was that great that a second pass avoided even in, say, the 1970s. But I may be wrong.

Comment: @einpoklum: Until the late 1980s, compilation times would often be dominated by sequential disk access speeds.  My point is that the Committee limited the meaning of the keyword to giving the compiler advance notice of something it could otherwise eventually discover for itself.  If the Committee had allowed compilers to treat the keyword as enabling optimizations in cases where the compiler *wouldn't* otherwise be able to prove that they were safe, that would have been extremely useful even today, but the Standard doesn't presently allow that.