# Why register storage class is explicitly deprecated

Tags: c++, standards

In numerical computation in mind, it seems to me that register storage class (which is currently deprecated and removed from the standard) was a good hint for optimization. Was there any specific reason for explicitly removing it from the standard?

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4193.html#809

Comment: Well, the optimizers got smart enough to figure it out themselves, so an extra keyword was no longer necessary. Write the code in a concise and readable way and let the compiler figure out optimizations. You usually do not know enough about the processor achitecture to help.

Comment: modern compilers already ignore the `register` keyword for decades. They decide which variables to keep in register through register allocation [Is it useless to use the `register` keyword with modern compilers, when optimizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43475229/995714)

Comment: Practically, `register` has only ever been a hint to the compilers that compilers are permitted to largely ignore, and most modern compilers largely ignore the hint because they can do a better job of optimisation than programmers. Practically, the net effect of using `register` has been little more than a means to prevent taking the address of a variable. Rather than worrying about micro-optimisations (like using `register`) focus on finding and using better algorithms - a programmer can achieve much more by picking better algorithms, clean coding, and letting a compiler sweat the small stuff

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answers. Although I do not fully agree with those reasons..

Comment: If you think you can do better than the compiler then there's still the option to write an optimised assembler routine. If it *really* gets better what the compiler does? Well, you'll have to profile/benchmark...

Comment: Of course you don't agree.  Novice programmers invariably think that they can optimise better than compilers.   With experience, they learn they are sadly mistaken.

Comment: Aconcagua well, that sounds very odd, because I believe I saw in TC++PL, one of the reason the C++ was designed was to free the programmers from necessity of the assembly routines to optimize their codes.

Comment: Peter perhaps you are right if C++ is designed for novices, however, I believe that C++ was designed for serious programmers, and letting open the possibility to suggest the compiler seems not very bad idea.

Comment: @user12924498 Well, newer C++ standards come with more and more possibilities to further optimise (consider move semantics since C++11 or [`likely`/`unlikely`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/likely) attributes coming with C++20 to give compiler additonal hints. But a compiler still is a general purpose tool that optimises in a way which is a compromise for a very wide range of scenarios. In some *very specific* ones those general purpose strategies don't produce optimal results.

Comment: In such a case a programmer might do better because he has some additional knowledge unavailable to the compiler. But that's *very* rare these days and only really experienced programmers will be able to actually produce better results than the compiler... Many times the programmer will start with the code generated by the compiler and only apply some minor tweaks to get yet a bit of performance out (usually this effort is only taken for time critical parts in high performance code, otherwise it isn't even considerd worth).

Comment: IIRC, there are now *optimal* register-allocation algorithms that did not exist when `register` was created. So no matter what you do, you can't do better than the compiler, and you're very likely to do worse.

Answer (score 8):

Because it is pretty much useless nowadays. `register` keywords is nothing more then a hint to the compiler that "you should try to give me fast access to this variable". But compilers are much better than you at measuring such things, especially if you're not actually benchmarking your code.

Comment: BTW, `inline` is also not really a hint to the compiler anymore. It's only there for breaking the ODR.

Comment: @Elazar Yeah meaning changed pretty much, similarly to `auto`, although the distance between new and old meaning might be even greater with the latter... And with the new meaning we can have inline variables as well...

Answer (score 5):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(keyword)):

> register is essentially meaningless in modern compilers due to optimization which will place variables in a register if appropriate regardless of whether the hint is given

EDIT:

[C++ Standard Defect reports](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4193.html#809)

> The register keyword serves very little function, offering no more than a hint that a note says is typically ignored. It should be deprecated in this version of the standard, freeing the reserved name up for use in a future standard, much like auto has been re-used this time around for being similarly useless.