# Why I cannot reallocate the *sm using realloc?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, realloc

I have this function in my program, in which the *sm pointer is showing error when reallocating. I have tried using malloc and free to manually resize the *sm but same error is showing in the free function.

```
char *numc_util_add_str(char **str, int s) {
    int size = 1;
    char *sm = (char *)malloc(size + 1);
    sm[0] = '0';
    sm[1] = '\0';
    while (s--) {
        int l = strlen(str[s]);
        int sz = l > size ? l : size;
        int t, r, car = 0;
        for (register int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
            t = (i <= l ? str[s][i] - 48 : 0) + (i <= size ? sm[i] - 48 : 0) + car;
            r = t % 10;
            car = t / 10;
            sm[i] = 48 + r;
        }
        if (car) {
            size++;
            sm = (char *)realloc(sm, size + 1);
            sm[size - 1] = 48 + r;
        }
        sm[size + 1] = '\0';
    }
    return sm;
}
```

This is showing when debugging:

```
    sm = (char *)realloc(sm, size + 1);
// Exception has occurred.
// Trace/breakpoint trap
```

Comment: Problem is actually a little later. `sm[size + 1] = '\0';` should be `sm[size] = '\0';`.

Comment: Tip: The name `size` is usually used for the amount of allocated memory. `len` would be a more appropriate name for what your variable holds: the length of a string.

Comment: Tip: `'0'` is more readable than `48`.

Comment: Tip: Don't cast the result of `malloc`. The only thing that can achieve is errors.

Comment: Could you explain what this is supposed to be doing? I can't figure out the logic of the `t=` line.

Comment: Tip: Don't use `register`. The compiler can figure this out on its own.

Comment: What does this have to do with WinAPI? It never calls any API functions.

Comment: `i <= l` should probably be `i < l`, and the same with `i <= size`.

Comment: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714), [Is it useless to use the `register` keyword with modern compilers, when optimizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43475229/995714), [Is the register keyword still used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10675072/995714), [Replacement for deprecated register keyword C++ 11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20618008/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning outside the bounds of `sm`.

This line:

```
int sz = l > size ? l : size;
```

sets `sz` to the larger of `l` and `size`. You then use `sz` as the bound of the `for` loop. In the loop you do:

```
sm[i] = 48 + r;
```

If `l` was larger than `size`, `i` will also become larger than `size`, but `size` is the maximum index of the `sm` array.

I don't understand what you're trying to do, so I'm not sure what the proper fix is. Maybe just do

```
sm = realloc(sm, sz);
```

before the `for` loop.